# Discord permission check not working dsicord js

Tags: discord, discord.js

For some reason when i try to use my command it keep giveing me this error. the error and the code is listed below. i tried fixing it nothing seems to fix it

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    aliases: ['purge'],
    discription: "clears messages",
    async execute(message, args, client) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.reply('You do not have permissions to use this command')
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply(`Please specify a amount of messages to delete (1-99)`)
        if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply(`Please enter a number`)
        if (parseInt(args[0]) > 99) return message.reply(` The max amount of messages you may delete is 99`)

        await message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0]) + 1)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        message.channel.send(`deleted ${args[0]} messages`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
    }
}
```

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:10108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you show the entire block of code where your line is? i.e. the whole `client.on('message', message => { ... }` part.

Comment: yea just edited the message

Comment: The error says the `member` property of your `message` object is undefined.  Are you sure your `(message, args, client)` are in the correct order as in your command handler (e.g. `command.execute(message, args, client)`)?  This error usually originates from not having your variables in the right order.

Comment: ahh yea that fixed it thanks it went (client, message, args)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    aliases: ['purge'],
    discription: "clears messages",
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel,send('You do not have permissions to use this command')
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply(`Please specify a amount of messages to delete (1-99)`)
        if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply(`Please enter a number`)
        if (parseInt(args[0]) > 99) return message.reply(` The max amount of messages you may delete is 99`)

        await message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0]) + 1)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        message.channel.send(`deleted ${args[0]} messages`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you should only send the part of the code you changed, with explanation. Secondly, you put a comma in message.channel,send